Why \let\footnote=\endnote Disables Hyperlinks and How to Fix It?
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=3.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\usepackage{endnotes}
%\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
               
\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
This is a sentence.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\chapter[Chapter 2]{}

This is another sentence.\footnote{This is another footnote.}

%\theendnotes
\end{document}

which produces



And so, it seems that the footnote hyperlinks have been added properly.
However, when I run the code with \let\footnote=\endnote and \theendnotes where indicated in the MWE, all the (footnote=endnote) hyperlinks disappear:




QUESTION: Does anyone know why this happens; and is there a simple fix for it?
Thank you.

well endnotes doesn't support hyperref. Consider to use something else, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669532/2388

@UlrikeFischer Thank you. It looks like this might be a useful link.

You can use enotez instead.
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=3.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\setenotez{backref=true}

\RenewCommandCopy{\footnote}{\endnote}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
               
\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
This is a sentence.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\chapter[Chapter 2]{}

This is another sentence.\footnote{This is another footnote.}

\printendnotes

\end{document}



Thank you for this helpful answer.

I have since discovered that an answer of Mensch found here Link does not work with endnotes and hyperref.sty can be adapted to solve the problem in an alternative way:
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%  
  pdftex,
  bookmarks=false,bookmarksopen=false,
  colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=red,urlcolor=blue,
  breaklinks=true,
  hyperfootnotes=true
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\usepackage{hyperendnote}

\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=3.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents            
               
\chapter[Chapter 1]{}
This is a sentence.\footnote{This is a footnote.}

\chapter[Chapter 2]{}

This is another sentence.\footnote{This is another footnote.}

\theendnotes
\end{document}

yielding the output:




